# How can I prevent CURL to turn '#' into a comment?

Tags: curl, cmd

I am using CURL in order to invoke an endpoint.

My endpoint has `#` as a part of it, e.g.

```
"http://Server.com/Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest#Trigger1"
```

When I call this endpoint with the CURL command it cuts my endpoint after the hash sign and I am left with:

```
"http://Server.com/Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest" ('#Trigger1' is missing)
```

I've tried to replace the has signed with `%23` and I get the following result:

```
"http://Server.com/Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest3Trigger1"
```

The full command that use:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"id":"1"}" "http://Server.com/Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest#Trigger1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you (correctly) use `%23` in the arguments, but you get

```
"http://...?...&arguments=-Arest3Trigger1"
                                ^
```

with missing `%2`, you are probably making the call from a batch file and the `%2` is being parsed as the second argument to the batch file (empty in this case).

If this is the case you will need to escape the percent sign by doubling it, using `%%23`.

From a batch file the line

```
curl "http://httpbin.org/anything?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest%%23Trigger1"
```

calling [`httpbin.org`](http://httpbin.org) request and response service will return

```
{
  "args": {
    "appname": "IFSCarolina_Prod",
    "arguments": "-Arest#Trigger1",
    "prgname": "HTTP"
  },
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.55.1"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "origin": "   .   .   .   ",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest%23Trigger1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much man that was so helpful you can't imagine :)

Comment: Maybe you could answer another question..
the data that i am posting to the endpoint is a json file that have repeting elements with squre brackets []  and it seem to disturb..

Comment: @RoiSolberg, If I have to bet your problem are the quotes. You can try to save the data you want to post inside a file and use `-d @x:\somewhere\file.json` to avoid having to deal with the command parser.

Comment: @RoiSolberg - If you have another question, create another post. SO likes discrete, to-the-point questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Curl doesn't turn `#` into a remark. The `#` sign and everything that follows is not meant to be sent to the server, and therefor curl doesn't.

The part before the `#` is sent to the server and determines what the server sends back.

In standard HTML, that part after the`#` is used to scroll to an anchor or an element with the given name.

With JavaScript in the browser, the script can determine the part after the `#` and use this to do whatever it wants to do.

But curl is not a JavaScript Interpreter, it just fetches data from a server, so it ignores the part after `#`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, is there any way to work around this so my endpoint will be complete?

Comment: If this answers your question, you could accept the answer. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will literally break the HTTP specs, but if you really want to do it (and you probably don't), I believe you can abuse `-X` to get it done:

```
curl 'http://Server.com' -X "$(printf 'GET /Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest#Trigger1 HTTP/1.1\r\nX-ignore-this: ')"
```

which will give you:

```
GET /Magicxpi4.6/MgWebRequester.dlll?appname=IFSCarolina_Prod&prgname=HTTP&arguments=-Arest#Trigger1 HTTP/1.1
X-ignore-this:  / HTTP/1.1
Host: Server.com
User-Agent: curl/7.63.0
Accept: */*
```

... But no sane HTTP server will actually require you to do this, if you want a hashtag in thre, urlencode it like `%23`... but that probably means you need a general-purpose URL-encoder too